# Execute Immediate Error: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have the following code, where I am trying to pass IF statement condition dynamically:

```
DECLARE
v_flag            NUMBER(2);
v_if_statement VARCHAR2(500);
v_sql_statement VARCHAR2(500);
v_criteria        VARCHAR2(150);
v_condition VARCHAR2(30) := '%sales% > 300';
BEGIN
v_criteria := REPLACE(v_condition , '%sales%' , 500.32);

      v_if_statement := 'IF :'||v_criteria||' '||
          'THEN :v_flag := 1;'||' '||
      'ELSE :v_flag := 0;'||' '||
          'END IF;';

v_sql_statement := 'BEGIN '||v_if_statement||' END;';         


      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_statement USING IN v_criteria, OUT v_flag;
       dbms_output.put_line('The output is : '||v_flag);

 END;
```

I get the following error:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks..

Comment: After building variable v_sql_statement, before executing it, print it out to see the full picture - then you can easily identify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print out your final generated statement as @Ychdziu suggested, you'll see it ends up as:

```
BEGIN IF :500.32 > 300 THEN :v_flag := 1; ELSE :v_flag := 0; END IF; END;
```

which isn't what you wanted. You either need to supply the value to be checked (500.32) as a bind variable as shown in @Ychdziu's answer, or concatenate the condition into the statement *without* trying to make that another bind variable:

```
DECLARE
  v_flag          NUMBER(2);
  v_if_statement  VARCHAR2(500);
  v_sql_statement VARCHAR2(500);
  v_criteria      VARCHAR2(150);
  v_condition     VARCHAR2(30) := '%sales% > 300';
BEGIN
  v_criteria := REPLACE(v_condition , '%sales%' , 500.32);

  v_if_statement := 'IF '||v_criteria||' '||
    'THEN :v_flag := 1;'||' '||
    'ELSE :v_flag := 0;'||' '||
    'END IF;';

  v_sql_statement := 'BEGIN '||v_if_statement||' END;';         
  dbms_output.put_line('statament: '||v_sql_statement);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_statement USING OUT v_flag;
  dbms_output.put_line('The output is : '||v_flag);

 END;
/
```

The generated statement is now

```
BEGIN IF 500.32 > 300 THEN :v_flag := 1; ELSE :v_flag := 0; END IF; END;
```

so there is only one bind variable.

But it's usually better to bind the variable if you can. In your example code the entire condition seems to be a variable (I assume this is just an exercise, but it could be passed in or come from a table), so you could combine both and replace the `%sales%` placeholder with a bind variable reference instead:

```
DECLARE
  v_flag          NUMBER(2);
  v_if_statement  VARCHAR2(500);
  v_sql_statement VARCHAR2(500);
  v_criteria      VARCHAR2(150);
  v_condition     VARCHAR2(30) := '%sales% > 300';
BEGIN
  v_criteria := REPLACE(v_condition , '%sales%' , ':v_value');

  v_if_statement := 'IF '||v_criteria||' '||
    'THEN :v_flag := 1;'||' '||
    'ELSE :v_flag := 0;'||' '||
    'END IF;';

  v_sql_statement := 'BEGIN '||v_if_statement||' END;';         
  dbms_output.put_line('statament: '||v_sql_statement);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_statement USING IN 500.32, OUT v_flag;
  dbms_output.put_line('The output is : '||v_flag);

 END;
/
```

Not the generated statement is:

```
BEGIN IF :v_value > 300 THEN :v_flag := 1; ELSE :v_flag := 0; END IF; END;
```

and you can pass the actual value you want to check, 500.32, directly via the `USING` clause - either as a literal as I've done here, or with a separate numeric variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this query:
1) The SQL statement itself is in bad structure;
2) DB tries to convert v_criteria to number type, but the v_criteria is '500.32 > 300' - you can't convert like that.
Try this way:

```
DECLARE
  v_flag            NUMBER(2);
  v_if_statement VARCHAR2(500);
  v_sql_statement VARCHAR2(500);
  v_criteria        VARCHAR2(150);
BEGIN
  v_criteria := 300.32;

  v_if_statement := q'[IF :v_criteria > 300
      THEN :v_flag := 1;
  ELSE :v_flag := 0;
      END IF;]';

  v_sql_statement := 'BEGIN '||v_if_statement||' END;';         
  dbms_output.put_line('v_sql_statement is : '||v_sql_statement);


  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_statement USING IN v_criteria, OUT v_flag;
  dbms_output.put_line('The output is : '||v_flag);

END;
```